# Multiwindow playground sample in Android Automotive N

Tags: android

Iam trying to run Android multiwindow sample https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MultiWindowPlayground on Android Automotive N. Inorder to switch app into split screen mode, it is suggested to long-press the recents button. Though the resizableactivity attribute is set true in Android manifest, it doesnot works in split screen mode in Headunit.

Please let me know how can I enable split screen mode in Android N Automotive Headunit?

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand your question, but fairly sure the point of Android Auto is to provide 'safe' access to some phone features, multi-window kinda defeats that purpose so I'm guessing the force it off in the Android Auto app.

Comment: I donot mean Android Auto but Android N.car sdk where I need to enable Multiwindow mode in Android Infotainment apps. Please let me know how https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MultiWindowPlayground can be run in multi-window mode?

Comment: @RamakanthKesireddy that's...android auto or at least a version of it, in any case my point still stands in that multi window is probably disabled